# Solving differential equation of damped oscillation with small parameter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I have a differential equation
$$\phi''+ k^2 \sin \phi + \eta S \phi'=0, $$
with $\phi(0)=a_0$, $\phi'(0)=0$. It's Damped oscillation.
I use the small parameter method, where $\mu=\eta$ is the small parameter.
solution $\phi(t)=\phi_0+\mu\phi_1+\mu^2\phi_2...$

I use a $\sin \phi$ Taylor series. So, how to convert the original equation to the system of linear differential equations? I tried to replace $k^2\sin \phi$ with $k^2\phi+\mu \frac{k^2}{\eta}(-\frac{\phi^3}{6}+\frac{\phi^5}{120}+...)$ but it's incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\eta$ is the small parameter, but $a_0$ is not small, you can't assume $\phi$ is small.  Instead, you should be expanding around the solution $\phi_0$ of the initial value problem with $\eta = 0$:
$$ \phi_0'' + k^2 \sin(\phi_0) = 0,\; \phi_0(0)=a_0,\; \phi_0'(0)=0 $$

We have

$$ \eqalign{ \sin(\phi) &=  \sin(\phi_0 + \eta \phi_1 + \eta^2 \phi_2 + \ldots)\cr
&= \sin(\phi_0) + \phi_1 \cos(\phi_0) \eta + \left(\cos(\phi_0) \phi_2 - \frac{\sin(\phi_0) \phi_1^2}{2} \right)\eta^2 + \ldots}$$

Then for each $k \ge 1$ the $\eta^k$ terms give you a linear initial value problem for $\phi_k$, but depending on $\phi_0, \ldots, \phi_{k-1}$.  Thus for $k=1$:
$$\phi_{{1}}''  +{k}^
{2}\cos \left( \phi_{{0}}   \right) \phi_{{1}}  = -S\phi_{{0}}' , \; \phi_1(0)=\phi_1'(0)=0 $$
and for $k=2$:
$$\phi_{{2}}''  +{k}^
{2}\cos \left( \phi_{{0}} \right) \phi_{{2}}  =\frac{{k}^{2}\sin \left( \phi_{{0}}  
 \right)  \left( \phi_{{1}}   \right) ^{2}}{2}-S\phi_{{1}}' ,\; \phi_2(0)=\phi_2'(0)=0 
$$

Comment: How did you get that $$\eqalign{ \sin(\phi) &=  \sin(\phi_0 + \eta \phi_1 + \eta^2 \phi_2 + \ldots)\cr
&= \sin(\phi_0) + \phi_1 \cos(\phi_0) \eta + \left(\cos(\phi_0) \phi_2 - \frac{\sin(\phi_0) \phi_1^2}{2} \right)\eta^2 + \ldots}$$ I'm not the sharpest tool in a shed))

Comment: Taylor series: $\sin(\phi) = \sin(\phi_0) + (\phi - \phi_0) \cos(\phi_0) - \frac{(phi-\phi_0)^2}{2} \sin(\phi_0) + \ldots$.  Expand $\phi - \phi_0$ and $(\phi - \phi_0)^2$ and take the terms in low powers of $\eta$.

Comment: So, I should find $\phi_0 \;$ from $\phi_0'' + k^2 \sin(\phi_0) = 0,\; \phi_0(0)=a_0,\; \phi_0'(0)=0$ (e.g. I can use $k^2$ as small parameter) and then substitude it into other equations?